# Issues downloading image drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**Javascript Code :**

```
window.onload = function () {
var canvas=document.getElementById("can");
var img=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var button = document.getElementById('saveImage');

    img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA'+
                'AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO'+
               '9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
    button.onclick = function () {
    window.location.href = img.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    window.location.href = prev;
             };
     };
```

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="can" width="500" height="200"></canvas><br />
<input type="button" value="Done" id="saveImage">
```

I am able to display the image on div from canvas but when i try to download it using above javascript function it downloads blank image. I want to know how can i get the picture drawn from the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

The biggest problem you're likely to face is that you can only save the image on the same server as the page which has the canvas element. You'll then have to retrieve that saved image (either server or client side) and prompt the user to save it.

EDIT:

Maybe this would be better, though you need a little bit of server-side code:
http://greenethumb.com/article/1429/user-friendly-image-saving-from-the-canvas/

Comment: i don't want the situation where user has to right click on the image to save it. The code which i have posted automatically downloads the image to the local machine. Problem is that i am not getting the image. All i get is blank image.

Comment: When I run that code the canvas is blank anyway (see http://jsfiddle.net/uyvN9/). This may be to do with the 'same server' policy in the link mentioned above.